# Neo4j LOAD CSV with multiple header rows

Tags: csv, neo4j, load, cypher

Given a CSV file with the following structure

```
   2015        2016
id attr1 attr2 attr1 attr2
 1     6   7.2     3   9.8
 .
 .
 .
```

is there a way to import the table directly into Neo4j with year nodes (2015, 2016), id nodes (1, 2, ...) and lots of `attr1` and `attr2` nodes with the necessary edges connecting the `attr` nodes to the correct year and id.

I know I could manipulate the CSV file in Python or something, but is there a way to do it within the Neo4j/Cypher query language as part of the `LOAD CSV` command?

Answer (score 0):

No, `LOAD CSV` only supports CSV with a single-line header (or no header at all).

Besides, that representation might be visually significant, but it's much harder to actually exploit from code. I'd argue it's not even CSV (with space separators) but a fixed-length file instead.